# accessing base class methods in SpEL

Tags: spring, spring-el, spring-cache

My class structure is as below:

```
package com.xyz.abc.controller;

public class Roles {
   public Static String REQ_ROLE = "LEARNER";
}

public class BaseController {
   protected String getRole() { return something; }
}

public class AccountController extends BaseController {
   @Cacheable(value="mycache", key="#accountId", condition="#root.target.getRole() == Roles.REQ_ROLE")
   public String getAccount(final @PathVariable String accountId) { return account; }
}
```

I am trying to call a base class function in condition of Cacheable using SpEL. However this throws an error saying :

```
Method call: Method getRole() cannot be found on com.xyz.abc.controller.AccountController type
```

How do i call the super method from this context?

Answer (score 2):

The method is not visible. Make it `public`.

Comment: Nope. It dint make a difference. I made getRole() public in the BaseController but i still get the same error.

Comment: I have the same issue, make parent method public works for me.